# Change Strings.xml with button?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Can I change a value in the strings.xml file of my project using `C#` when a button is pressed? I'm doing a text game and debating whether to change the string values or start new activities.

Comment: If my answer helped please mark it as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Strings are hard-coded in the string.xml file and can't be changed in runtime.

If you want to update strings values, use [Settings](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings) plugin that allow you get and store strings in application settings.

If you will need to get and store a big bunch of strings consider using database (eg: [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet) or [SQLite](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)).

Answer (score 1):

No.  Files that are embedded into the project bundle are read-only.